# How to iterate over Directories in Ant

Tags: ant

I've a root directory and it contains many directories,in turn each sub-directory contains many directories and so on.For example if "A" is  a root directory it contains sub-directories "A.a","A.b",so on... and each directory("A.a","A.b",etc) contains many directories.I want to copy the inner directories of "A.a" , "A.b" ,etc.. to other directory structure similar to the "A".Instead of copying the each directory I want to use loop that iterates every directory and it's sub-directories(even files).How to do that...Please help me out as I'm new to Ant...

Answer (score 1):

For copying, use 'copy' and 'fileset':

```
<copy todir="./destination/dir">
    <fileset dir="./source/dir">
        <include name="**/*" />
    </fileset>
</copy>
```

The include directive inside the fileset will cause Ant to review each directory recursively.

Other tasks that involve files and directories (such as move for ftp) will also accept filesets.